# How to label bars on a barplot and how to change axis title in R Studio?

Tags: r, bar-chart, axis-labels

I'm new to R and I am having difficulties labeling my bar plot in such a way that its easy to read and clean. Right now the bar plot has labels but its very polluted. And I also cant seem to figure out how to label my x axis without breaking my code. This is the code with dummy data:

```
data<-cars
line_numbers<-c(1, 37, 73,109,145,193)
cars$speed<-as.Date(cars$speed)
col_leg<-c("purple")
p<-barplot(cars$dist~cars$speed,ylim=c(0,max(cars$dist*1.25)),
ylab="speed",xlab="distance"
,col=col_leg)
labels=c("2002", "2005", "2008", "2011","2014","2018")
axis(side=1,labels=labels, at=line_numbers)
text(p,100,cars$distance,cex=0.75,pos=3,srt=-90)
```

Comment: hi, interesting, not sure if this might help http://howtoinr.weebly.com/customize-labels1.html